# Unable to publish global array variable

Tags: javascript

```js
let Array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]

for (i = 0; i <= Array.length; i++) {
  let j = Math.abs(Array[i] - 1); // [0, 1, 2, 4, 4]
  Array[j] = Math.abs(array(j) *- 1); // [-1, -2, -3, 5, -5]
}
console.log(Array);
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined

Can anyone please explain to me why my array will not console.log. I'm sorry if this is a really rudimentary question. Thank you

Comment: Avoid creating a variable named `Array` because there's a javascript constructor function with the same name. Change every `Array` variable name to `array` or something else. Error in your code is because of the second line of code inside the loop. You have named the variable `Array` but inside the loop, on the second line, you are referring to is using the name `array`. Also note the use of `()` brackets in `array(j)`, you probably meant to use `[]` brackets: `array[j]`

Answer (score 2):

You cant create Array var since it is a reserved word for constructor Array

Answer (score 0):

Because Array is a reserved Javascript word, you need to use an array (lowercase).
Change Array -> array;

And you need to change parentheses to square brackets `Array[j] = Math.abs(array(j) *- 1);`
to `Array[j] = Math.abs(array[j] *- 1);`

**Solution**:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]

for (i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
  let j = Math.abs(array[i] - 1); // [0, 1, 2, 4, 4]
  array[j] = Math.abs(array[j] *- 1); // [-1, -2, -3, 5, -5]
}
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a variable named `Array` since it is a reserved word for the constructor [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array).